# SwiftUI 5: How to lock orientation for a specific view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13

On my camera view, I want to keep the orientation as portrait because when it's in landscape, the camera preview does not rotate:

```swift
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        
        //...
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        
        // starting session
        camera.session.startRunning()
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

I know I'll need to fix this sooner or later but I need to get moving. For now, I'll prevent all other orientations except:

```swift
struct CameraView: View {
    init() {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

[..]
```

By doing the above, when put in landscape, the camera preview cuts in half then the `init` "kicks in" which sets it back CameraView back into portrait. How to let it stay in portrait mode without any animation?

Placing the code inside `.onAppear` does nothing:

```swift
struct CameraView: View {
  var body: some View {

    VStack{..}
      .onAppear(perform: {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out I've fixed the rotation instead:

```swift
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let statusBarOrientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
    let videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation = statusBarOrientation?.videoOrientation ?? .portrait
    camera.preview.frame = view.frame
    camera.preview.connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
}
```

For `videoOrientation` see [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505962/3581788).

```swift
import AVFoundation

extension UIInterfaceOrientation {
    var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation? {
        switch self {
        case .portraitUpsideDown: return .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeRight: return .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeLeft: return .landscapeLeft
        case .portrait: return .portrait
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```